# Basic Authentication Retirement MS Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-basicauth

Can someone tell me if it will still be possible to use following authentication method with MS Graph after October 13, 2020?

```cs
public static async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
{
    String APIToken = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX";
    String LoginMail = "xxx@xxx.be";
    String LoginWachtwoord = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    UserPasswordCredential userPasswordCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(LoginMail, LoginWachtwoord);

    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/diekeure.be");

    //Console App for Microsoft Graph
    AuthenticationResult token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", APIToken, userPasswordCredential);

    return token.AccessToken;
} /* GetUserAccessTokenAsync */

public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
{
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async (requestMessage) => {
                string accessToken = await GetUserAccessTokenAsync();

                        // Append the access token to the request.
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
            }));
    return graphClient;
} /* GetAuthenticatedClient */

-> await graphClient....
```

Nuget package: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.19.8

I'm not really sure of this won't work either

Comment: I don't fully understand, are you asking if AAD will work with the OAuth password grant after this date? Its an oddly specific date, where are you getting it from?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: I've got an email om 21/09 from O365 about 'Basic Authentication Retirement for legacy protocols in Exchange Online'. Linking to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/Upcoming-changes-to-Exchange-Web-Services-EWS-API-for-Office-365/ba-p/608055

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample isn't using Basic Authentication, it is using the OAuth Password grant. While not a very secure authentication mechanism (since you have to store a password), it is quite different than Basic Auth.

The email you referenced is also specific to *legacy* services like Exchange Web Services (EWS). Microsoft Graph is *not* a legacy API, it is the recommended/modern REST API for Microsoft services.

Comment: I created this code instead of the EWS I was using. But I wasn't sure if it was OK. Now I know, thank you!